# Manage Visibility of button in Horizontal Recycler list view

Tags: android, position, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal center zoom image list in which i want to display play icon and text for center scale view only

I am able to scale center Imageview but getting position problem while managing it through model.

But sometimes it displays and sometimes not. but i am getting position of center imageview perfectly in class onScrollStateChanged method.

Following class i have used for layout manager and scrollview in my activity

```
  mAdapter = new ContactScreenAdapter(ContactScreenActivity.this, mContext, listFavoriteContact);
        scrollZoomLayoutManager = new ScrollZoomLayoutManager(this, Dp2px(25));
        recyclerFavoriteList.setLayoutManager(scrollZoomLayoutManager);
        recyclerFavoriteList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerFavoriteList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                if (!(layoutManager instanceof CircleLayoutManager) && !(layoutManager instanceof ScrollZoomLayoutManager)) {
                    mAutoSet = true;
                    return;
                }

                if (!mAutoSet) {
                    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        final int dx;
                        if (layoutManager instanceof CircleLayoutManager) {
                            dx = ((CircleLayoutManager) layoutManager).getOffsetCenterView();
                        } else {
                            dx = ((ScrollZoomLayoutManager) layoutManager).getOffsetCenterView();
                        }
                        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(dx, 0);
                        Log.d(TAG,"####  dx : "+ ((ScrollZoomLayoutManager) layoutManager).getCurrentPosition());
                        mAdapter.setSelecteditem(((ScrollZoomLayoutManager) layoutManager).getCurrentPosition());

                    }
                    mAutoSet = true;
                }
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING || newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                    mAutoSet = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

and i am updating my model in adapter method

```
  public void setSelecteditem(int selecteditem) {
    this.selectedItem = selecteditem;

    for (int i=0;i<moviesList.size();i++){
        moviesList.get(i).setCenterSelected(false);
        Log.d("CSA","##  moviesList.get(i).isCenterSelected() : "+ moviesList.get(i).isCenterSelected());
    }
    moviesList.get(selecteditem).setCenterSelected(true);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Use `Handler.post()` to perform the action on a next frame.

Comment: could you please help me with the code snippet and where to put.